# detecting orientation in iPad iframe on window resize (or when orientation changes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, iframe, orientation

THe thing is we need iframe, so the partner can just add url and we can control what is displayed in it without needing to have their website code.

If not iframe, it looks ok.

But with iframe it is a problem - window height is always bigger than width. And various methods just thinks that its portrait. As I understood the heihgth is how much content there is and iframe does not have scrolls. So iframe for my code is like browser window, not parent real browser window.

There have been various questions, but I still not able to find working solution.

**Update:**

I found how to make it not go over in height - on window load, take window height and set that height to the div and overflow: scroll. So whole window does not get more high and so iframe does not get so high. On load window height is the initial iframe height. Still not managed yet to detect orientation correctly, because now for some reason when portrait - width is still higher than height, with is 960, at least that what javascript see, but in reality it is not going over boundaries, which are 768px.

Now tried to find out who make it have 960px. And went to this:

```
function test2() {
        ?>
    
            <iframe src="" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
   
        <?php 
    }
```

this is empty content with 100% width, and why it is 960px? Not only for ipad, but using chrome emulation, I see its for other popular mobile devices also.

So if height is lets say 500, and widht is 960, it thinks that its landscappe. But in real ipad does not have 960px width, it has 768. And does not go wider even when javascript detects 960. How can this be?

**Update:**

To detect widht I use:

```
$(window).load(function(){  
   var width = $(this).width();
});
```

and it gets wider screen width. Maybe iframe is wider and has horizontal scroll, but iPad does not draw a scroll but it is possible to move it horizontally while parent page stays same position.

But just checked with test page iframe - iPad does not let scroll horizontally and page fits in the iframe but still it detects window width 964px, while it should be 768

ALso in the testing page, iframe is in the div, div has style width: 768px !important;
and iframe also has style width: 768px !important;

and still iPad shows width 964 :)

**Update:**

Currently solved on partner page in hacky way: intially one of the inside divs I make css width: 300px, and then so I get good window widht. Then since I want wide 85%, I multiply widow width * 0.85 and set it to that div which I want to be wider. Earlier I tried to achieve the same with css widht: 85% which caused to become wider than screen. Still this does not make sense, but works.

Comment: try putting the width and height to the parent container and on iframe use scrollable css property it will suffice ur need

Comment: you mean overflow: scroll?

Comment: made parent container like 700px height, but on iPad it does not care about that height and goes over it still

Comment: height: 500px !important; width: 900px !important; overflow: auto !important; -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important;

Answer (score -2):

Use this css on parent container:

```
height: 500px !important; 
width: 900px !important; 
overflow: auto !important; 
-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch !important;
```

Comment: this forces it not not become higher than 500px, but $(window).load(function() {}).resize(function(){ // get called and height is still 1156px and so it things it is always portrait here })

I mean resize gets called on load already. Before resize gets called, it see as landscape.

Comment: is ur iframe parent container is also reloading or resizing?

Comment: parent container was not resizing, as I remember iframe itself went over it. But I found how to make it not go over in height - on window load, take window height and set that height to the div and overflow: scroll. So whole window does not get more high and so iframe does not get so high. 
On load window height is the initial iframe height. 
Still not managed yet to detect orientation correclty, because now for some reason when portrait - widht is still higher than height, with is 960, at least that what javascript see, but in reallity it is not going over boundaries, which are 768px.

Comment: to detect the window orientation you can use orientation event of javascript

Comment: @ Kunal Vashist - I believe that it works when javasript detects height and width properly. But in my case it is not detecting properly. That is the biggest problem I think.

Comment: javascript always detect the height and width.. if it is not detecting then it might be problem in your code...